# Regular expression containing lambda

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

What is the meaning of lambda here: 
$$(b+c)^*(a+\lambda)(b+c)^*(a+\lambda)(b+c)^*(a+\lambda)(b+c)^*$$.

I know that lambda is used in the context of NFA?

Let's suppose we break down the expression to:$$(b+c)^*(a+\lambda)(b+c)^*$$

and to:$$(b+c)^*(a+\lambda)(b+c)^*(a+\lambda)(b+c)^*$$

How the above would generate an empty string?
Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lambda$ denotes the empty string, which is written `""` in programming languages. The regular expression you give matches the empty string because you can choose each "$a+\lambda$" to match $\lambda$, and each "$(b+c)^*$" to match zero copies of $b+c$. So the expression matches, among other things, $\lambda\lambda\lambda\lambda\lambda\lambda\lambda$, which is just the same thing as $\lambda$.

Comment: How many a's can we generate from:  (a+lambda)(a+lambda)?

Comment: Each bracket matches one $a$ or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To generate an empty string you take: $(b+c)^*$ as $\epsilon$, and all the following elements which have a Kleene-star as $\epsilon$ (I will use $\epsilon$ instead of $\lambda$).

Then you have: $$\epsilon(a+\epsilon)\epsilon(a+\epsilon)\epsilon$$
Which is equivalent to: $$(a+\epsilon)(a+\epsilon)$$

Which is essentially picking two options a or $\epsilon$ twice back to back. If you take $\epsilon$ transition each time, which is actually a transition that does not consume an input, it will essentially accept an empty string as input.